# Trying to repair a dual boot, but no idea what to do

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

I have installed Linux alongside Windows several times, and it always just worked, but something has gone wrong this time. The PC has a bit of a messy history. Sorry this is long - trying to give enough context to get help that works.

EDIT: Sorry for the woolly description before (below). I used fdisk and gparted to get the information below. sdb can be ignored for now, I guess. I manually created sda3 and sda4 before installing 18.04 the other day. sda2 is just some data. sdc is where all the Windows action is.

Things have move on a little. I learned enough about the GRUB prompt to boot properly. The environment has an incorrect root and prefix so I do this:

```
set root=(hd5,gpt3)             # was (hd7,gpt2) or something 
set prefix=(hd5,gpt3)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

And then a GRUB menu appears. Yay! Unfortunately, I have been unable to work out how to make these settings permanent. That would at least avoid typing to boot.

The other problem is the BIOS/UEFI business. I tried sorting things out with:

```
sudo grub-mkdevicemap
sudo update-grub
```

It did create a device map file, but there were errors about there being no boot partition. I got bogged down in trying to install GRUB (or is it GRUB2?) and didn't have any idea what I was doing. I created the partition sda5 but think that was a mistake. I'm very nervous of breaking sdc2. Or is that the partition I need to update?

In the BIOS UI, I can choose to boot from "Windows Boot Manager" (maybe sdc2?), then Windows boots. Or I can choose "ubuntu (P6: KINGSTONSV300S3)" (maybe sdc6?), then I get the GRUB prompt and have to change the root and prefix.

Thanks for any help on this.

Al

```
fdisk
-----
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6D0962C5-7B63-4C18-BDF8-9616B5C15B90

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          34     262177     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      264192 1024264191 1024000000 488.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1024264192 1922701311  898437120 428.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  1933993984 1953523711   19529728   9.3G Linux swap
/dev/sda5  1922701312 1923827711    1126400   550M BIOS boot

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F5BFEA3D-D474-4558-8116-863A43F44D08

Disk /dev/sdc: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1EABA5B3-E873-4B05-B9BC-0ACEC835C34F

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1       2048    616447    614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdc2     616448   1148927    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sdc3    1148928   1411071    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc4    1411072  14723071  13312000   6.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc5   14723072 466805926 452082855 215.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc6  466806784 467937279   1130496   552M Windows recovery environment


gparted
-------
Model: ATA WDC WD1003FZEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   524GB   524GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 3      524GB   984GB   460GB   ext4
 5      984GB   985GB   577MB                                                 bios_grub
 4      990GB   1000GB  9999MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  316MB   315MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      316MB   588MB   273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      588MB   722MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      722MB   7538MB  6816MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, msftdata
 5      7538MB  239GB   231GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      239GB   240GB   579MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
```

### Woolly history

The PC came with an SSD (Windows - now identified as **sdc** for some reason) and a regular HDD (**sda**), on which I installed Ubuntu. This was all totally fine.

I later added a larger HDD (now called **sdb**) to the machine, but unplugged **sda** for lack of another SATA cable. I guess that was pretty dumb. I eventually got a cable and plugged smaller HDD back in, resulting in the current enumeration for the drives, I guess. Surely the newest one should be **sdc**? Can they change? No matter.

So. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the big HDD (before the small one was restored to power) and it worked mostly fine. For some reason, I was not offered a dual boot option. I manually created partitions for root and swap, and let the installer go from there. **A GRUB menu appeared on booting, but did not list Windows as a option**. For months I have had to halt booting with F2 and manually selected the boot device. Not good. Aside from that, I simply could not get the OS to work with two monitors (one is 4K and apparently this is an issue). I was so fed up with this pickle that I thought I'd start over.

I removed all Linux partitions from all drives, with the intention of creating a clean sheet. Probably also dumb. I did not know this, but this does not get rid of GRUB, which became very unhappy. After an evening of trying to understand how to clean up the Windows boot sector or whatever to no avail, I changed the boot disk priorities and got the PC to just start Windows. Fine. But I want a dual boot machine.

Today I have tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 onto **sda**. I was once again not offered a dual boot option, so manually created partitions for root and swap, and told the installer to use **sda**. I hoped that this would fix things. It didn't. GRUB now dumps me at a prompt and I have no idea what to do there. I'm guessing I need to update the menu somehow.

I have a feeling that some of this might be tied to UEFI, another thing I know nothing about, but which seems to have made life harder.

I'd be very grateful for some assistance in patching this up.

Thanks.

Al

Comment: Consider editing your question to include detailed information about the current partitioning setup. You can get this by using `gparted` on the live USB. I got lost in all the history.

Comment: If Windows is UEFI, you need to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. It sounds like you installed in BIOS boot mode. You also need drive partitioned as gpt, not old MBR(msdos). This will erase drive, so have good backup. Gparted: Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu With multiple drives only use Something Else install option.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI